# Get transform from mouse click position

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, mouseclick-event

Tried this a million ways, always get conversion errors. I am simply clicking around, against a plane, would like mouse position at click to get pumped into a transform variable so that my character walks towards that point. I'm using `var target: Transform;` to define where the character moves. How can I extract that type of variable from a click in world space, which will intersect with a plane (or anything)?

```
var WalkingSpeed = .05;

// The target marker.
var target: Transform;

// Speed in units per sec.
var speed: float;

static var mousePos : Vector3;

function Update() {
    // get distance between objects current position and the target position
    var distance = Vector3.Distance (target.transform.position, transform.position);

    if(distance > 0) {
        // we are still not at the target, do walking animation
        animation["walk"].speed = 1;    // set speed of animation
        animation.CrossFade("walk");    // actually play the animation
    } else {
        animation["idle"].speed = 1;    // set speed of animation
        animation.CrossFade("idle");    // actually play the animation
    }
    //Debug.Log(distance);

    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

    // Also rotate towards the point
    var targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
    var newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0);
    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, newDir, Color.red);   // draw something showing direction (for debug)

    // on click, set new target position
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        var posVec = Input.mousePosition;
        posVec.z = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(posVec);

    }
}
```

This one in particular throws cannot convert vector3 to transform

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do it, which depend on the kind of camera you are using. Attach either script to the object you want to move and you are done. Make sure you put it in the `Update()`.

#### The Orthographic

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    var posVec = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    posVec.z = transform.position.z;

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posVec, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

#### The Perspective

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
 {
     var posVec = Input.mousePosition;
     posVec.z = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
     posVec = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(posVec);

     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posVec, speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

---

I would also like to point out that `transform.position` is a `Vector3`.

I can tell your script is already attached to the GameObject that you want to move. Therefore, you don't even need `target`.

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posVec, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

will work correctly.

---

[**Video proof that code works**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXb5QzgufDw).

Comment: but if var "target" which is a Transform, and I want to set that to the position of the mouse click, I get Cannot convert 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'.

Comment: In your code `target : Transform` is my `transform.position`. So you would type: `target.position = Vector3 . . . ` Just copy the code, it will work.

Comment: @prismspecs Because you wrote `target`. Again it should be `target.position`. In reality you don't even need `target` you can do it using `transform.position` just like my code above.

Comment: that just makes the player float off into the sky if the mouse is being held down

Answer (score 2):

give your plane a collider and get the position of the hit with raycasting

```
  public Vector3 pos;
     void Update () {
             if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                  Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                 RaycastHit hit;
                  if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))     
                      pos=hit.point;           

              } 
     }
```

Comment: but this is the exact same problem where i don't want a vector3, but a transform position from the raycast hit

Comment: Beautifully done, thank you! Could anyone elaborate on what @FunctionR means by it being "overkill for performance"? Is this going to cause a problem? I only expect to use this when the user needs to tell a character on screen to move to a location. It won't be firing automatically.